# Removing rows based on duplicate columns in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I've come across some similar questions, but I still don't quite understand.

I have a MySQL database with a table in which I store data of people and unique codes. The base unit for me is the e-mail address. I want to select random records, but limit them so a specific email column can be selected only once. This is my table structure (I'm leaving some columns, that are not relevant to this question).

```
+-----+-------------------+---------+----------+----------+
| ID  | email             | name    | lastname | code     |
+-----+-------------------+---------+----------+----------+
|  1  | mail@gmail.com    | Simon   | Hardy    | 123ABC   |
|  2  | john@yahoo.com    | John    | Doe      | EEEEEE   |
|  3  | john@yahoo.com    | John    | Doe      | AEAEAE   |
|  4  | xyz@bing.com      | Bill    | Liebe    | 5D78AC   |
|  5  | ellen@gmail.com   | Ellen   | Petete   | 99AQE5   |
|  6  | john@yahoo.com    | John    | Doe      | 000CVV   |
|  7  | peter@gmail.com   | Peter   | Lorem    | 54ACSS   |
|  8  | emma@gmail.com    | Emma    | Stone    | 98WW7Q   |
+-----+-------------------+---------+----------+----------+
```

If I limit my selection to 3 rows and somehow the row with email = john@yahoo.com got selected, I need the other two rows with this email to be ignored/skipped. This is my query now:

```
SELECT * FROM people ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 3
```

PS: I know "ORDER BY RAND()" is slow, I just didn't focuse on that part yet.

I was thinking about GROUP BY, but as far as I understand that way I would only get that one column, I need to fetch all of them.

Is there a straightforward solution for this in MySQL?

Comment: Why are `email`, `name` and `lastname` duplicated? Can't you use a users table and a code table containing a field with a foreign key to the user table?

Comment: That was my first thought. But users tend to enter their personal data differently (capitall letters, spaces, special characters etc.). Would it still be a better way?

Comment: [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) ! Otherwise, it's WET.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In MySQL 8+, you can use:

```
SELECT p.*
FROM people p
ORDER BY ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY email ORDER BY RAND())
LIMIT 3;
```

If you want to solve both the performance problem and the duplication problem at the same time . . . that is challenging.  My recommendation is to select a smaller number of rows and just "hope" that there are enough different emails.

For instance, for 3 emails you might want to get about 100 rows with something like this:

```
select p.*,
       (@rn := if(@e = email, @rn + 1,
                  if(@e := email, 1, 1)
                 )
       ) as rn
from (select p.*
      from people p cross join
           (select count(*) as cnt from people) pp  -- can use primary key index
      where rand() < (100 / cnt) -- get about 100 rows
      order by email, rand()  -- only on about 100 rows
     ) p cross join
     (select @e := '', @rn := 0) params
having rn = 1
limit 3;
```

Comment: Limiting the rows to a lower number is not really an option, because I need it to be 'fairly' random. I've tried the first query you posted above, but I'm getting this error: Unknown table 'mytable.p'null

Comment: @KristiánFilo . . . The first query is a small typo.  The second does what you want -- it returns a random set of rows with unique emails.  Note that the `where` clause is being used to get a random sample from the table, and then this is whittled down to three rows for the result set.

Comment: Ah, I understand now. Thank you. Question: If I limit the results to, say 50, but I only have 10 unique emails, is the correct behavior for the first query to show duplicates even though it should not?

Comment: @KristiánFilo . . . Yes.  The first query will return 50 rows, in groups of unique emails.  In your case, it would return 5 rows for each email, assuming that there are five.

Comment: Very straightforward and well documented reply, thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT**

SELECT * FROM Test
WHERE id IN
(SELECT MIN(id) FROM Test GROUP BY email) LIMIT 3;

this should do.

Comment: He wants to fetch all columns

Comment: You can't do that. You have fields non-aggregated used with a group by